# Update data in DB using CURL command

Tags: c#, asp.net, curl, webapi

I'm trying to update the data in the database using the CURL command through WebAPI controller. What is the command to do that ?

Comment: The command is `curl`. The parameters will depend on your specific URL, header and body requirements, etc.

Comment: I'm not able to find the syntax for updating the data in the DB using curl. I'm trying to insert JSON through webapi

Comment: curl cannot update a database. All it can do is send a request to your webapi. If you are able to craft a request that works using Postman then you can use its [code generation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/) feature to create the curl command. It is impossible to give you a specific answer because we have no idea how your api/controller is implemented.